# Creating Data Frame from the combination of list,dictionaries and Tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I started learning python Recently. I have a problem below.

I have written the function which returns different type of values eg like below .

```
def example():
    #calculations
    return dictionary, list, tuples, single_value_variable

#Calling the function
dic,li,tu,sv = example()
```

I am returning the values like following . And I want to convert this values into data frame

```
  ({'1': 'abc',
    '2': 'def',
    '3': 'ghi'}
    ,[T,F,T],
    ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')),  
    20)
```

I have tried with following code but it's not giving the expected results

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dic':pd.Series(dic), 'list':li,'Tuple':tu, 'Single Value':sv}) 
res = df.set_index(['sv'])
print(res)
```

I am expecting the results something like below

[image]

I would be really grateful if someone could help me to achieve this . Thanks a lot in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are after, but this code provides something like what you are looking for.

```
data =  ({'1': 'abc', '2': 'def', '3': 'ghi'}, [True,False,True], (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')), 20)

dictlist = []
for k in data[0]:
    dictlist.append(str(k) + "," + data[0][k])

df = pd.DataFrame({"dict": dictlist, "list": data[1], "tuple": data[2], "Single value": data[3]})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    dict   list   tuple  Single value
0  1,abc   True  (a, b)            20
1  2,def  False  (c, d)            20
2  3,ghi   True  (e, f)            20
```

Comment: tuple has four values but its returning an error when i add fourth one - and also i want to be displayed 20  for one time

Comment: You would have to add NA values to the other types to match the length of the tuple array. Note that dataframes are not the right format to visualise this kind of data. I don't think it is possible to merge the Single Values into one cell. Probably just storing the data in a dictionary is best practice here. What is your goal with your dataframe?